# Can't get Laravel 4.2 to hash my passwords

Tags: php, laravel, hash, laravel-4, passwords

I've hashed passwords many times but can't seem to get it to work on a client's site.

Here is my controller:

```
class ListingController extends BaseController   {


public function create()
{

    return View::make('listing.listing');
}

public function store()
{
    $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), Listing::$rules, Listing::$messages);
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    $data['passsword'] = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

    Listing::create($data);

    return Redirect::to('/success')->with('message', 'Thank you, the listing has been submitted.');
}
}
```

And the portion of my form dealing with the password:

```
<div class="form-group">                
{{Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' =>     'Password', 'tabindex' => '11'])}}
</div>
```

Am I blind? Have a missed something? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you var_dump `$data['passsword']`?

Comment: Do you have any setter of `password` inside your `Listing` class?

Comment: Yes I did that first.

`["password"]=> string(5) "password"`

Comment: No, just the code you saw.

Comment: So `Hash::make()` does not hash the password?

Comment: No. That's the issue.

Comment: There is a typo in `$data['passsword']`. Shouldn't it be _password_?

Comment: I just noticed that. What an amateur mistake. Thanks you for your help.

Comment: There is a typo in `$data['passsword']`.